# Saving a checklist with values of checkboxes in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

For a web application I need to make some kind of checklist for users. The checklist is administrated by a special administrator account and only he can edit the checklist. Each user has it's own checklist with certain conditions which has to be checked when that condition is met. Also I added a textbox for any comments (if there are any)

I constructed a few tables in a MySQL database:
A users database which has the data of all registered users

A table called checklist properties with the following columns:

```
property_idnr | type | description
```

Next a table which links the user with the property with the following columns:

```
link_idnr | user_idnr | property_idnr | comments
```

Now my question is, did I set this up properly? Also, I am having a bit of an issue with the Query's.. what is the best way to store these values in the database?

I hope someone is able to help me out with this, if you need any more information, please ask!

Comment: Your schema design looks good. But what is the role comments? Is each user going to add comment for each checklist they have?

Comment: The idea is that I have the regular user and an administrator user. The administrator manages the checklist for each user and can tick and untick the property and put an comment, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema looks reasonable.  To get the list for a given user, you would use a query like this:

```
select clp.type
from CheckListLink cll join
     CheckListProperties clp
     on cll.property_id = clp.property_id
where cll.user_id = <user_id>
```

What I would suggest adding is an ordering column into the CheckListLink table.  Different users may have their check list ordered in different ways.  Also, I would add a datetime column to all the tables, so you know when the records were created.

Storing the values . . . Well, you need a way to set up the possible items in the check list.  And, then you need a way for users to choose the items they want in their check list.  From a database perspective, this is just a question of various insert statements (perhaps deletes as well).  The bigger challenge is on the UI side.

Comment: Alright, thanks! yeah  I think saving it into the database is the biggest challenge since you need to determine when a value needs to be deleted or added.. I already have a UI setup with the list of checkboxes. I think it's mostly figuring out the Query's now. :P